# i keep getting unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

why do i keep getting unhandled promised rejection

Unhandled promise rejection. This 
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

```
(async () => {

    try {
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: data[i].subscription[0].totalPrice + "00",
            currency: 'usd',
            customer: customer.customerid,
            payment_method: customer.paymethod,
            off_session: true,
            confirm: true,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        // Error code will be authentication_required if authentication is needed
        console.log('Error code is: ', err.code);
    }

})();
```

Comment: Where is the actual error?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(async () => {


        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: data[i].subscription[0].totalPrice + "00",
            currency: 'usd',
            customer: customer.customerid,
            payment_method: customer.paymethod,
            off_session: true,
            confirm: true,
        })

})().catch(e=> {console.error(e)})
```

Comment: Updated based off https://medium.com/@JonasJancarik/handling-those-unhandled-promise-rejections-when-using-javascript-async-await-and-ifee-5bac52a0b29f

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys the above code is working, The error was on a different async function but i was able to fix it because of @Omi in a hellcat post  medium.com/@JonasJancarik/… Thanks